# Find all the vectors $v=(a,b) \in \mathbb{R}^2$ for which sets are tight frames

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra

Find all the vectors $v=(a,b) \in \mathbb{R}^2$ for which sets

1. $B=\{ (1,0), (0,1), (1,1), (a,b) \}$
2. $B_1=\{ (a,b), (a,-b), (1,0) \}$

are tight frames (but not necessarily Parseval frames) in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

About I supoose to find that? What I tried doing was computing $B^TB$ where B is the matrix and then try to find the eigenvalues but then I have 3 unknowms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A frame is tight if and and only if the frame operator $B^TB$ is a multiple of identity. So, the off-diagonal entries must be zero and the diagonal entries must be equal to each other.

Also, in the book *Frames for Undergraduates* (Han et al.) there is a chapter on frames in two dimensions with the following neat characterization. Interpret the frame vectors as complex numbers $z_1,\dots,z_k$: then the frame is tight if and only if $z_1^2+\dots+z_k^2=0$. This becomes clear after you write down the $2\times 2$ matrix of the frame operator in terms of $z_j$ and invoke the first paragraph above.

For example: $B_1$ is tight iff $(a+ib)^2+(a-ib)^2 + 1 = 0$, which amounts to $a^2-b^2+1=0$.